# Create PDFs from HTML and CSS in Express (server side)

Tags: node.js, express, pdf

I want to be able to create a PDF and send it via an email to the user in Express.js. My current tech stack contains: Next.js for the frontend and Express.js at the backend.

Basically, I want to send out an invoice to the user after the payment has been made. I'm currently sending an email, but I want to create a PDF and attach it with the same email. The invoice will be HTML-based, which means I'll have HTML tags like header tags, tables, etc. and CSS for these elements.

My front-end (Next.js/React) are actually not relevant here, because all the data required for the invoice is handled by Express.js itself. So, I'm considering using jsPDF to do this, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I don't use Pug in Express, but I want to dynamically create the HTML and use that to create the PDF.

Can anybody give me a direction here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you know any React, there's [React PDF](https://react-pdf.org/) that allows you to create PDFs, you could then save them locally before sending them, that might be an option, but it's not really HTML though.

Comment: Thanks. But I'd prefer a backend solution, because the moment the payment is done, I get the booking details from the database and send the email. And I'd like to make sure that the invoice is in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [pdfjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs) is something you want I guess. You can create your own HTML templates with placeholders for the variables that you might want to keep dynamic. You can easily find out a lot of examples on this on the internet to satisfy your requirement.